Getting number values after Excel data import
I imported text from a text file that has text and numbers into excel using data import using text/csv import option. I used space as the delimiter. After the data is imported, the numbers have trailing spaces. Because of these spaces, it is treated as text. If I remove the spaces, excel recognizes it as numbers, otherwise not. what can I do to fix the issue either during import or what formula can I apply to get the number value? I tried TRIM and it does not work in this case.
I tried Trim(cell#) and still I don't see the number value in the formula

TRIM() might not work if they are special characters that appear as spaces, such as new line or tab characters.  Easy way is to Copy the "space" character and then use Find & Replace and paste the copied "space".  Replace All with nothing and it should get you there.

Consider cleaning the text file of special characters before importing it into Excel

If the numbers are properly placed in their own column you could just select the column and search and replace (CTRL + SPACE) a space with nothing. Power Query would be a good tool to clean and load into Excel.

Not sure I understand the first solution. How do I copy the space character in all the cells in the sheet?

If you are using the space as the delimiter during import, no spaces should be entering your worksheet. This suggests that the 'spaces' are actually a special kind of space, such as non-breaking spaces.
The non-breaking space is typically character 160 in Excel. (This might differ depending upon your regional settings.) So you can create a non-breaking space using CHAR(160).
You probably then need some combination of the following:

TRIM() - to remove leading and trailing spaces;
CLEAN() - to remove (some) non-printable characters;
SUBSTITUTE() - to remove non-breaking spaces;
VALUE() - to convert a "texty" number to a real number.

You can use SUBSTITUTE() to remove non-breaking spaces from cell A1 like this:
=SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(160), "")

So you could try a formula like:
=VALUE(CLEAN(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(160), ""))))

(As above, TRIM() shouldn't be strictly necessary if you are using the space as your delimiter character for import.)
If this doesn't work, you might need to find out exactly which special characters are polluting your data. You can do that by applying the following formula to a problem cell:
=CODE(MID(A1, n, 1))

This will return the nth character code for the first character of cell A1. Vary n as required to get the code you need. Then you can apply SUBSTITUTE() as above, using this code.
